# Slider with a control template thumb affects the value?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, slider

I'm noticing some odd (but logical) behavior with a slider I have where I've overridden the Thumb control template that I'd like to override. This isn't the full XAML, but it's the critical parts. The red rectangle is the grip and it has a white horizontal line in the middle of it.

```
<Slider VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"/>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid Margin="0,1,0,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Border Name="PART_Border"
                    Background="White"
                    Height="1"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Grip" Fill="Red" Height="50" Width="15" ClipToBounds="True"/>
        </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In the code behind, if I hook up the template to the thumb in the slider's style, it gives me a nice little slider like this which is what I want.

[image]

However, once I start sliding it around, I notice that the functionality is slightly different when you have the `Rectangle`. As your drag up, the `Thumb` reaches the end of the track (crudely demonstrated in green here) but `Thumb` will stop at the top of the rectangle which means the white line does not properly align with the track's tick value.

[image]

If you delete `Rectangle PART_Grip` from the `Grid`and slide it all the way up like this, the white line will be aligned with the last tick like so:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Grid Margin="0,1,0,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Border Name="PART_Border"
                        Background="White"
                        Height="1"/>
            </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

[image]

How would one position the `Rectangle` in the `Grid` in such a way that allows for the rectangle to go beyond the end of the track but the white line will be aligned with the ticks and still be centered? I tried the `Rectangle` as an `Adorner` instead, which worked, but it didn't seem possible to trigger `DragDelta`on `Thumb` properly so you could not drag the thumb up. Perhaps there is a way to override the tick functionality and offset by the `Rectangle` height without going the `Adorner` route?

What I'd like to see:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two different ways to do this.

A straight negative margin offset that is 1/2 the height of the `Grip` which in this case is 50.

```
<Grid Margin="0,-25,0,-25">
```

This works well.

A slightly more complicate way: nest a canvas, and margin the `Grip` directly.

```
<Grid>
    <Border/>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Grip" Margin="0, -25, 0, 0"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

The canvas allows you to do stuff like have the grip follow the mouse easily enough if that's how you want to roll.
And of course, this also works if the orientation is horizontal, it's just the width instead of the height and the top instead of the left margin.